# predict continuous values using sklearn bagging classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, bag

Can I use sklearn's `BaggingClassifier` to produce continuous predictions? Is there a similar package? My understanding is that the bagging classifier predicts several classifications with different models, then reports the majority answer. It seems like this algorithm could be used to generate probability functions for each classification then reporting the mean value.

```
trees = BaggingClassifier(ExtraTreesClassifier())
trees.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = trees.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I do not see the point in bagging a `ExtraTreesClassifier`. It already uses bagging. Increasing the number `n_estimators` should have the exact same effect. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @maxnoe I think you are right. The knn classifier would be more realistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in predicting probabilities for the classes in your classifier, you can use the [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.predict_proba) method, which gives you a probability for each class. It's a one-line change to your code:

```
trees = BaggingClassifier(ExtraTreesClassifier())
trees.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_pred = trees.predict_proba(X_test)
```

The shape of `Y_pred` will be `[n_samples, n_classes]`.

If your `Y_train` values are continuous and you want to predict those continuous values (i.e., you're working on a regression problem), then you can use the [`BaggingRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor.html) instead.

Comment: Cool thank you.'predict_proba' is indeed what I am loking for. It is a classification problem.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use BaggingRegressor() for continuous values, and then compare performance with RMSE.  example below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingReressor
trees = BaggingRegressor()
trees.fit(X_train,Y_train)
scores_RMSE = math.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, trees.predict(X_test))
```