# sklearn use prob_a to for logistic binary classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

Is there some way to report the expected value of a sklearn model binary classification model?  In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191959/predict-continuous-values-using-sklearn-bagging-classifier) someone recommended `predict_proba`. I was expecting an output similar to the xgboost package `"objective": "binary:logistic"` parameter. However, it seems like this does not produce the desired results. My Y train values are discreet.

I am confused by the output of `predict_proba`. As I only have one objective, I was expecting a single column prediction to be returned. However, this returns two columns, and these columns sum to one. These values do not seem to correspond to the values actually predicted by the model:

```
In [27]: modl.predict(X_test)
Out[27]: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])

In [28]: modl.predict_proba(X_test)
Out[28]: 
array([[ 0.6,  0.4],
       [ 0.7,  0.3],
       [ 1. ,  0. ],
       ..., 
       [ 1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.9,  0.1],
       [ 0.8,  0.2]])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The columns in the output array from `predict_proba` are the probabilities of the different labels being predicted by your classifier. In your case, you've built a binary classifier, so the first column `modl.predict_proba(X_test)[:,0]` is the probability of the label being `0` and the second column `modl.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]` is the probability of the label being `1`.